# What is the default window size when running Selenium tests over Azure Pipelines?

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines

I am running headless Selenium tests on Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) with ChromeDriver—see the article here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops on how to set this up.

I have an issue where tests fail due to an element not being visible and I suspect it's because of the media queries in CSS which force a different layout than expected. (I am expecting to test the desktop rendering of the site.)

What is the default window size for Selenium when running on a VSTS build?

Comment: it's been a while, but last time I tried it was 0x0px. Making sure your tests set the resolution and the window size as part of your test initialization is important :).

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in a previous comment, you can set window-size and start chrome maximized using ChromeOptions, such as (in C#):

```
// use headless chrome
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments(new List<string>()
                    {
                        "--headless",
                        "--disable-gpu",
                        "--no-first-run",
                        "--no-default-browser-check",
                        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
                        "--no-sandbox",
                        "--window-size=1280,1920",
                        "--start-maximized",
                        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                    });
WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(".", options);
```

*Note: I am use **Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v75.0.3770.140**, and running on an Azure DevOps Services **Windows 2019 with VS2019** agent, which is currently configured with **Chrome v75.0.3770.100***

Comment: Note: you can check your Azure DevOps Chrome version by clicking "Pool Information" above where your Agent type is selected, in order to make sure your Chromedriver is a similar version.