# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' error while taking screenshot with headless Chrome using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I have been trying to mess around with selenium in python and was running it on linux.  I have it setup that it can get the website but since I am using it in a headless environment, I wanted to take as screenshot so I can see whats going on.  When ever I try to get a screen shot I just get this message as shown below:

[image: as shown here]

My python code is as follows:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

#Setup Chrome in headless
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

#Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www/google.com")

#Capture the screen
driver.save_screenshot("screen.png")
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit inconclusive behind the reason you see the error as:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

However, if you are using the latest version of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [python](/questions/tagged/python) clientsi.e. *Selenium v3.141.0*, instead of `add_argument("--headless")` you need to set the `headless`  attribute as **`True`**.

---

I was able to execute your own code block with the change mentioned above and some minor tweaks as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.headless = True
  options.add_argument('window-size=1400,600')
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www/google.com")
  driver.save_screenshot("screen.png") #Capture the screen
  driver.quit()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)
- [How to set window size in Selenium Chrome Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python/55016352#55016352)

Comment: After I set headless to True, I couldn't get the option to add extensions

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem recently for

- serverless-chrome [v1.0.0-53](https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/tag/v1.0.0-53)
- ChromeDriver 2.41.578700

The reason was that the image size was too big.

So decrease the window size e.g. to 768x1024

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
...
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=768x1024')
```

And if you are doing full page screenshots - limit the height

```py
width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
height = height if height < 10000 else 10000
driver.set_window_size(width, height)
driver.save_screenshot(image_path)
```