# how to resize window via webdriver selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, resize, window

The question is how to resize the browser window (e.g. chrome window) via webdriver selenium with python. This question is re-edited: The alternative thread-question in ref [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python) does not provide the solution, because it creates confusion: basically they say the suggested solution for resizing does not work. However, the answer provided here avoid such confusion and solves the problem. I'd suggest to edit the title of the question in ref [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python) to something similar to "*how to resize window with webdriver-selenium-python when the method `.set_window_size` fails*". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple this, (e.g. window size 1200x600)

```
driver.set_window_size(1200,600)
```