# How to get the coordinates of all visible objects from web page with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, parsing

I am trying to render a website to get the coordinates of human-visible objects from an HTML page. I can get the coordinates of a specific object with Selenium, but I need the coordinates of all objects. The main problem is to filter the divisions where there is information and where they are transparent (I attach a picture), how can I do it?
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window() # now screen top-left corner == browser top-left corner 
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")
question = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Newest")
y_relative_coord = question.location['y']
browser_navigation_panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
y_absolute_coord = y_relative_coord + browser_navigation_panel_height
x_absolute_coord = question.location['x']
print(x_absolute_coord, y_absolute_coord)
```

Made some additions, but for some reason does not want to work correctly

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
y_relative_coord = []
x_absolute_coord = []
contours = []
list_of_visible_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath( "//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]")
for element in list_of_visible_elements:
    y_relative_coord = element.location['y']
    size = element.size
    w, h = size['width'], size['height']
    browser_navigation_panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
    y_absolute_coord = y_relative_coord + browser_navigation_panel_height
    x_absolute_coord = element.location['x']
    x = [x_absolute_coord, y_absolute_coord, w, h]
    contours.append(x)
    
img = cv2.imread('screenshot.png')
result = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cntr
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("bounding_box", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**UPD**
I've improved the code a bit and it seems to work fine but still not very accurate, how could the results be improved?

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
driver.save_screenshot("s.png")
y_relative_coord = []
x_absolute_coord = []
contours = []
list_of_visible_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath( "//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]")
for element in list_of_visible_elements:
    y_relative_coord = element.location['y']
    size = element.size
    w, h = size['width'], size['height']
    browser_navigation_panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
    y_absolute_coord = y_relative_coord + browser_navigation_panel_height
    x_absolute_coord = element.location['x']
    if x_absolute_coord !=0 and y_absolute_coord !=0 and w != 0 and h != 0 : 
        x = [x_absolute_coord, y_absolute_coord, w, h]
    
        contours.append(x)
    
img = cv2.imread('s.png')
result = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cntr
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.imshow("bounding_box", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
try: 
    os.remove("s.png")
except: pass
```

[image]

Comment: `driver.maximize_window()` - what if a monitor resolution is different then you expect?

Comment: @vitaliis Can I use a fixed window resolution?

Comment: Yes, `driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)` Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to use `//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))` and use `find_elements` instead of `find_element` to have all visible web elements in a list.

XPATH which says give me all visible elements or directly all the elements whose display is equal to none.

**Code :**

```
y_relative_coord = []
x_absolute_coord = []
list_of_visible_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]")
for element in list_of_visible_elements:
    y_relative_coord = element.location['y']
    browser_navigation_panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
    y_absolute_coord = y_relative_coord + browser_navigation_panel_height
    x_absolute_coord = element.location['x']
    print(x_absolute_coord, y_relative_coord)
```

Comment: @Nikita Kit : Updated the code with `browser_navigation_panel_height` variable

Comment: And how do I understand the coordinates of what exactly I got?

Comment: so this is tricky since all the web elements are different. your best bet is to go ahead with class name or get the text for each web element. in the loop you can try something like this `print(element.text)`

Comment: That's the problem, I could filter by class name, but I need to do it for different sites, and there these names can be different

Comment: @NikitaKit : Well I figured out something for ya, check out this loop `for element in list_of_visible_elements:
    print(element.rect, element.location, element.text)`

Comment: Can you check my changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.execute_script` to run a recursive generator function in Javascript that will traverse all the visible DOM nodes and return only those coordinates which are within the browser window height:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python')
r = d.execute_script("""
function* get_nodes(root){
   var style = window.getComputedStyle(root)
   if (style.getPropertyValue('display') != 'none'){
       if (root.offsetTop <= (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight)){
          var b_d = root.getBoundingClientRect()
          yield [b_d.x, b_d.y, b_d.width, b_d.height]
       }
       for (var i of root.childNodes){
          if (i.nodeType === 1){
             yield* get_nodes(i)
          }
       }
   }
}
return [...get_nodes(document.body)]
""")
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 1200, 3519.9375], [0, 0, 1200, 0], [0, 0, 1200, 50], [0, 3, 1200, 47], [0, 3, 166, 47], [0, 3, 166, 47], [8, 9.5, 150, 30], [166, 10, 261.59375, 33], [168, 12, 68.359375, 29], [168, 12, 68.359375, 29], [240.359375, 12, 86.484375, 29], [240.359375, 12, 86.484375, 29], [330.84375, 12, 94.75, 29], [330.84375, 12, 94.75, 29], [427.59375, 9.703125, 628.9375, 33.59375], [439.59375, 9.703125, 604.9375, 33.59375], [439.59375, 9.703125, 604.9375, 33.59375], [1056.53125, 3, 143.46875, 47], [1056.53125, 10, 143.46875, 33], [1060.53125, 10, 59.453125, 33], [1123.578125, 10, 68.421875, 33], [1200, 26.5, 0, 0], [0, 50, 1200, 3147.9375], [0, 50, 164, 3147.9375], [0, 50, 164, 605], [0, 74, 154, 573.171875], [0, 74, 154, 573.171875], [0, 74, 154, 34], [0, 74, 154, 34], [8, 78, 142, 26], [8, 78, 35.765625, 26], [0, 124, 154, 221], [0, 124, 154, 221], [8, 124, 146, 14], [0, 142, 154, 33], [0, 142, 154, 33], [30, 150, 65.515625, 17], [8, 361, 146, 14], [0, 383, 154, 264.171875], [13, 396, 120.6875, 33], [13, 472, 129, 105.796875], [164, 50, 1036, 3147.9375], [189, 74, 663, 2952.1875], [189, 74, 663, 59], [189, 74, 547.984375, 35], [189, 74, 311.1875, 35], [748.984375, 74, 103.015625, 59], [748.984375, 74, 103.015625, 37.78125], [189, 133, 663, 121], [189, 133, 663, 85], [407.65625, 282.59375, 42.265625, 13], [470.109375, 282.59375, 35.015625, 13], [525.3125, 282.59375, 50.53125, 13], [579.84375, 282.59375, 24.109375, 13], [624.140625, 282.59375, 70.125, 13], [189, 318.1875, 663, 0], [189, 318.1875, 663, 243.1875], [190, 319.1875, 661, 182], [186, 319.1875, 669, 182], [202, 335.1875, 161.40625, 150], [202, 331.1875, 161.40625, 104], [202, 331.1875, 57.8125, 19], [202, 358.1875, 161.40625, 19], [200, 358.1875, 165.40625, 19], [202, 361.1875, 13, 13], [202, 361.1875, 13, 13], [219, 358.1875, 83.859375, 19], [202, 385.1875, 161.40625, 19], [200, 385.1875, 165.40625, 19], [202, 388.1875, 13, 13], [202, 388.1875, 13, 13], [219, 385.1875, 144.40625, 19], [202, 412.1875, 161.40625, 19], [200, 412.1875, 165.40625, 19], [202, 415.1875, 13, 13], [202, 415.1875, 13, 13], [219, 412.1875, 82.34375, 19], [395.40625, 335.1875, 157.53125, 150], [395.40625, 331.1875, 157.53125, 158], [395.40625, 331.1875, 69.796875, 19], [395.40625, 358.1875, 157.53125, 19], [393.40625, 358.1875, 161.53125, 19], [395.40625, 361.1875, 13, 13], [395.40625, 361.1875, 13, 13], [412.40625, 358.1875, 55.421875, 19], [395.40625, 385.1875, 157.53125, 19], [393.40625, 385.1875, 161.53125, 19], [395.40625, 388.1875, 13, 13], [395.40625, 388.1875, 13, 13], [412.40625, 385.1875, 105.40625, 19], [395.40625, 412.1875, 157.53125, 19], [393.40625, 412.1875, 161.53125, 19], [395.40625, 415.1875, 13, 13], [395.40625, 415.1875, 13, 13], [412.40625, 412.1875, 79.5625, 19], [395.40625, 439.1875, 157.53125, 19], [393.40625, 439.1875, 161.53125, 19], [412.40625, 439.1875, 100.5625, 19], [584.9375, 335.1875, 234.65625, 150], [584.9375, 331.1875, 234.65625, 77], [584.9375, 331.1875, 87.3125, 19], [584.9375, 358.1875, 234.65625, 19], [582.9375, 358.1875, 238.65625, 19], [584.9375, 361.1875, 13, 13], [584.9375, 361.1875, 13, 13], [601.9375, 358.1875, 121.03125, 19], [584.9375, 385.1875, 234.65625, 19], [582.9375, 385.1875, 238.65625, 19], [584.9375, 388.1875, 13, 13], [584.9375, 388.1875, 13, 13], [601.9375, 385.1875, 133.46875, 19], [608.9375, 412.1875, 210.65625, 37], [608.9375, 412.1875, 210.65625, 37], [611.9375, 421.6875, 73.171875, 16], [613.9375, 419.28125, 69.171875, 24], [662.109375, 423.28125, 16, 16], [685.109375, 415.1875, 23, 29], [708.109375, 421.6875, 0, 16], [189, 2942.1875, 0, 16], [876, 74, 300, 3084.9375], [876, 74, 300, 371], [877, 74, 298, 358], [877, 74, 298, 41], [877, 127, 298, 34], [893, 127, 22.15625, 34], [915.15625, 127, 243.84375, 34], [915.15625, 127, 208.8125, 33], [877, 173, 298, 51], [893, 173, 22.15625, 51], [915.15625, 173, 243.84375, 51], [915.15625, 173, 236.59375, 50], [877, 755, 298, 42], [889, 762, 274, 25], [889, 762, 67.984375, 25], [1163, 762, 0, 25], [877, 797, 298, 966], [877, 797, 298, 920], [877, 797, 298, 115], [877, 797, 298, 115], [889, 806, 40, 100], [889, 806, 32, 32], [929, 803, 234, 103], [929, 806, 234, 32], [929, 841, 234, 16], [929, 841, 33.234375, 15], [969.234375, 841, 86.09375, 16], [983.234375, 841, 72.09375, 16], [929, 860, 234, 16], [929, 860, 81.953125, 16], [929, 861, 81.953125, 13], [1017.953125, 860, 63.390625, 16], [1017.953125, 861, 63.390625, 13], [929, 879, 31.84375, 24], [962.84375, 879, 48.296875, 24], [929, 906, 234, 0], [1153, 803, 16, 16], [1071.640625, 776, 97.359375, 22], [877, 912, 298, 99], [889, 921, 40, 84], [889, 921, 32, 32], [929, 918, 234, 87], [929, 921, 234, 16], [929, 940, 234, 16], [929, 940, 57.96875, 15], [993.96875, 940, 114.015625, 16], [1007.96875, 940, 100.015625, 16], [929, 959, 234, 16], [929, 959, 78.109375, 16], [929, 960, 78.109375, 13], [1014.109375, 959, 63.390625, 16], [1014.109375, 960, 63.390625, 13], [929, 978, 48.296875, 24], [979.296875, 978, 51.125, 24], [929, 1005, 234, 0], [1153, 918, 16, 16], [1071.640625, 891, 97.359375, 22], [877, 1011, 298, 115], [889, 1020, 40, 100], [889, 1020, 32, 32], [929, 1017, 234, 103], [929, 1020, 234, 32], [929, 1055, 234, 16], [929, 1055, 82.40625, 15], [1018.40625, 1055, 114.015625, 16], [1032.40625, 1055, 100.015625, 16], [929, 1074, 234, 16], [929, 1074, 63.390625, 16], [929, 1075, 63.390625, 13], [929, 1093, 49.171875, 24], [980.171875, 1093, 32.234375, 24], [929, 1120, 234, 0], [1153, 1017, 16, 16], [1071.640625, 990, 97.359375, 22], [877, 1126, 298, 99], [889, 1135, 40, 84], [889, 1135, 32, 32], [929, 1132, 234, 87], [929, 1135, 234, 16], [929, 1154, 234, 16], [929, 1154, 58.796875, 15], [994.796875, 1154, 114.015625, 16], [1008.796875, 1154, 100.015625, 16], [929, 1173, 234, 16], [929, 1173, 81.984375, 16], [929, 1174, 81.984375, 13], [1017.984375, 1173, 63.390625, 16], [1017.984375, 1174, 63.390625, 13], [929, 1192, 51.125, 24], [982.125, 1192, 64.421875, 24], [929, 1219, 234, 0], [1153, 1132, 16, 16], [1071.640625, 1105, 97.359375, 22], [877, 1225, 298, 131], [889, 1234, 40, 116], [889, 1234, 32, 32], [929, 1231, 234, 119], [929, 1234, 234, 48], [929, 1285, 234, 16], [929, 1285, 82.921875, 15], [1018.921875, 1285, 114.015625, 16], [1032.921875, 1285, 100.015625, 16], [929, 1304, 234, 16], [929, 1304, 78.5625, 16], [929, 1305, 78.5625, 13], [1014.5625, 1304, 63.390625, 16], [1014.5625, 1305, 63.390625, 13], [929, 1323, 51.125, 24], [982.125, 1323, 67.234375, 24], [1153, 1231, 16, 16], [1071.640625, 1204, 97.359375, 22], [877, 1356, 298, 115], [889, 1365, 40, 100], [889, 1365, 32, 32], [929, 1362, 234, 103], [929, 1365, 234, 32], [929, 1400, 234, 16], [929, 1400, 52.46875, 15], [988.46875, 1400, 114.015625, 16], [1002.46875, 1400, 100.015625, 16], [929, 1419, 234, 16], [929, 1419, 77.3125, 16], [929, 1420, 77.3125, 13], [1013.3125, 1419, 63.390625, 16], [1013.3125, 1420, 63.390625, 13], [929, 1438, 48.984375, 24], [979.984375, 1438, 67.234375, 24], [929, 1465, 234, 0], [1153, 1362, 16, 16], [1071.640625, 1335, 97.359375, 22], [877, 1471, 298, 131], [889, 1480, 40, 116], [889, 1480, 32, 32], [929, 1477, 234, 119], [929, 1480, 234, 32], [929, 1515, 234, 32], [929, 1515, 150.71875, 15], [929, 1531, 95.8125, 16], [943, 1531, 81.8125, 16], [929, 1550, 234, 16], [929, 1550, 63.390625, 16], [929, 1551, 63.390625, 13], [999.390625, 1550, 88.953125, 16], [999.390625, 1551, 88.953125, 13], [929, 1569, 48.296875, 24], [979.296875, 1569, 64.421875, 24], [1153, 1477, 16, 16], [1071.640625, 1450, 97.359375, 22], [877, 1602, 298, 109], [889, 1611, 32, 32], [929, 1608, 234, 103], [929, 1611, 234, 16], [929, 1630, 234, 32], [929, 1630, 217.78125, 15], [929, 1646, 79.0625, 16], [943, 1646, 65.0625, 16], [929, 1665, 234, 16], [929, 1665, 63.390625, 16], [929, 1666, 63.390625, 13], [929, 1684, 49.171875, 24], [980.171875, 1684, 48.296875, 24], [929, 1711, 234, 0], [1153, 1608, 16, 16], [1071.640625, 1581, 97.359375, 22], [0, 0, 1200, 655], [487.9937438964844, 341.8999938964844, 223.99685668945312, 18.600006103515625], [487.9937438964844, 368.8999938964844, 223.99685668945312, 55.556243896484375], [487.9937438964844, 370.1000061035156, 223.99685668945312, 30.600006103515625], [487.9937438964844, 370.1000061035156, 223.99685668945312, 30.600006103515625], [489.1937561035156, 382.70001220703125, 221.59689331054688, 18], [487.9937438964844, 403.1000061035156, 223.99685668945312, 20.15625], [697.5906372070312, 332.29998779296875, 24, 24.600006103515625], [665.859375, 3229.9375, 198, 171], [665.859375, 3229.9375, 198, 34], [665.859375, 3229.9375, 121.0625, 33], [786.921875, 3229.9375, 0, 16], [665.859375, 3275.9375, 198, 125], [665.859375, 3275.9375, 198, 25], [665.859375, 3275.9375, 87.84375, 25], [665.859375, 3300.9375, 198, 25], [665.859375, 3300.9375, 76.75, 25], [665.859375, 3325.9375, 198, 25], [665.859375, 3325.9375, 138.375, 25], [665.859375, 3350.9375, 198, 25], [665.859375, 3350.9375, 65.9375, 25], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 50, 3.59375, 17]]
```

Comment: is it possible to get the height and width of rectangles?